# How to debug "internal server error"?

Tags: php, apache, apache2, internal-server-error

When you do changes to .htaccess files and something is wrong with it you get "Internal server error". That doesn't help me. How can I find out what's the actual error?

Comment: Check your webserver logs.

Comment: I did and there's nothing in them. r u talking about /var/log/apache2?

Comment: check your web server log. double check you are looking at the correct logs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error cause should be saved in server logs. Where it's exactly depends on your server and settings.

Eg. in apache2 log file is defined in `ErrorLog` in your config or in virtual host.

Comment: ErrorLog is set to ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_log. How can I find out what value has ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} lol?

Comment: @thelolcat `lol`? Is it funny that you don't know how to find that value? Check lines before that and check where is it set.

Answer (score 2):

In the case it is a syntax error, enabling debug may not help you. If you can, run built-in php syntax checker to ensure your file is free from errors:

```
>> php -l path/to/your/file.php
```